# How do I float a header nav tag to the right?

Tags: html, css, web, layout

Question

I've looked over the code very carefully and can't see a reason at all whatsoever why the header nav float isn't working in the stylesheet. I'm including all the html code and css code down below. I want to move my 
header nav to the right in my css code so that my links appear on the top right corner of my home page horizontally.

```css
body {
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*Global*/
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

/* header */

header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #000 3px solid;
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}


header li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
    float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Home Section */

#home {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url("http://www.ridgedesign.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Ridge-Design-Website-Design-Background.jpg") 0 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#home h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#home p {
    font-size: 20px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Home</title>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding"><span class="highlight"><h1>James 
Velardi</span></h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>laskfj;jla;jal;j;aljs;lasj;lasjl;ajsdlajsdl;fajsldfkjals;dfjalsdkfjalsf</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems that become quite obvious if you look at the page in the browser inspector:

- The first is that you have floated the branding div, and floating an element removes it from the regular flow and it isn't full width anymore, so the navigation that is inside is put below the heading.
- You have mixed the opening and closing tags of `<h1>` and `<span class="highlight">` and this caused that the block `<h1>` is being *inside* of the inline `<span>`, at least in Firefox.

Compare this screenshot of your example in the Firefox inspector:

[image: Your code in the browser inspector]

With this other one of the adjusted code:

[image: Answer code in the browser inspector]

Remember, browser inspector is your friend.

```css
body {
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*Global*/
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

/* header */

header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #000 3px solid;
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}


header li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
    /*float: left;*/
}

header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Home Section */

#home {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url("http://www.ridgedesign.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Ridge-Design-Website-Design-Background.jpg") 0 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#home h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#home p {
    font-size: 20px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Home</title>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding"><h1><span class="highlight">James 
Velardi</span></h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>laskfj;jla;jal;j;aljs;lasj;lasjl;ajsdlajsdl;fajsldfkjals;dfjalsdkfjalsf</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you, I also noticed that I forgot to close the #branding div, which was why the nav and the branding were in the same block.

Answer (score 0):

I added `class="nav"` to the navigation unordered list and set position to absolute using a `.nav` selector.

```
.nav {
  position:absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right:0px;
}
```

You can change the position by adjusting top and right values.

```css
body {
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*Global*/
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

/* header */

header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #000 3px solid;
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav {
  position:absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right:0px;
}

header li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
    float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Home Section */

#home {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url("http://www.ridgedesign.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Ridge-Design-Website-Design-Background.jpg") 0 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#home h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#home p {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding"><span class="highlight"><h1>James 
Velardi</h1></span>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>laskfj;jla;jal;j;aljs;lasj;lasjl;ajsdlajsdl;fajsldfkjals;dfjalsdkfjalsf</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your #branding div being floated left is breaking it--and doesn't seem necessary since you want that left aligned anyway.

It works for me with:

```
#branding {
    float: none
}
```

Also - in your html you need to move your floated .**nav** div before the .**highlight** span

Comment: We just stopped supporting older browsers and started doing these things with flexbox css and it's nearly effortless, if you want to approach it that way too - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/